# Can I set a field to be a function for each instance with Ember-Data?

Tags: rest, ember.js, ember-data

Is it possible to have Ember-Data fill in the code of a computed property or method with code provided by the server for each object?

We have a number of objects that behave like an Enum, in that there is a relatively fixed number of them, but each of the instances has some special logic to compute validity. We'd like to be able to pass the code for that to Ember as part of a "normal" Ember-Data REST call to load in the object from the server, but I can't seem to find anything supporting or refuting that capability.

For example, say we have some date ranges:

- last week
- last month
- month to date
- custom

and we also have some aggregations:

- hourly
- daily
- weekly

and each of the aggregations is only valid for certain date ranges, based on some algorithm that is unique to each aggregation.

Is it possible to fill in the body of a method (eg. "isValid(dateRange)")for the aggregation when loaded by Ember-Data over REST?

<sub>Note: The goal of this is that the date ranges and aggregations (and their validity functions) can and will change, but we don't want to have to make the change on the server, as well as in the client app</sub>